# Get libtool library output filename

Tags: automake, libtool

I'm trying to define an Automake rule that will generate a text file containing the full path to a libtool library that will be built and installed by the same Makefile. Is there a straightforward way of retrieving the output filename for a libtool library (with the correct extension for the platform the program is being built on)?

For example, I am trying to write something like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la

bar.txt:
  echo $(prefix)/lib/$(libfoo_la) >$@
```

Where `$(libfoo_la)` would expand to `libfoo.so`, `libfoo.dylib` or `libfoo.dll` (or whatever else),  depending on the platform. This is essentially the value of the `dlname` parameter in the resulting libtool library file. I could potentially extract the filename directly from that, but I was hoping there was a simpler way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not a way I've found of doing this.
Fortunately, for you, I did have a little sed script hacked together that did kind
of what you want, and hacked it so it does do what you want.

**foo.sed**

```
# kill non-dlname lines
/^\(dlname\|libdir\)=/! { d }

/^dlname=/ {

# kill leading/trailing junk
s/^dlname='//

# kill from the last quote to the end
s/'.*$//

# kill blank lines
/./!d

# write out the lib on its own line
s/.*/\/&\n/g

# kill the EOL
s/\n$//

# hold it
h
}

/^libdir=/ {

# kill leading/trailing junk
s/^libdir='//

# kill from the last quote to the end
s/'.*$//

# paste
G

# kill the EOL
s/\n//
p
}
```

**Makefile.am**

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la

bar.txt: libfoo.la foo.sed
        sed -n -f foo.sed $< > $@
```

Comment: Is the presence of `sed` more reliable than the presence of `grep` and `awk`? I am currently just using this: `$(GREP) dlname $< | $(AWK) -F "'" '{print $$2}' >$@`, which also achieves the desired effect.

Comment: No, not really.  They are both in the list of [usual tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Limitations-of-Usual-Tools.html).  However this way also appends the `libdir` from the .la file which should be the correct path where the lib is installed.  I noticed on your rule to build `bar.txt` that you are writing `$(prefix)/lib/libfoo.` _extension_  into `bar.txt`.  This won't be correct all the time (e.g. on 64-bit platforms `$(prefix)/lib64/libfoo.` _extension_).

Comment: Fair point - I guess I should have use `$(libdir)` instead of of `$(prefix)/lib`.