# How do I get a list of symbols from an automake/libtool library?

Tags: automake, libtool

I am the maintainer of [twolame](http://www.twolame.org/), a MPEG Audio Layer 2 encoding library. It is built using autoconf/automake/libtool.

As part of the build/test process I would like to get a list of visible/exported symbols and compare it to a version controlled file, to ensure that only the expected symbols are visible.

On Mac OS, I can use `nm -g libtwolame/.libs/libtwolame.dylib` to successfully get a list of the symbols. I intend to then write a script to extract the symbols from the `nm` output and compare it to a file as part of the `make check` target.

But am not sure how to calculate the path of the binary library in a script. Is there a way to ask `libtool`, to take `libtwolame/libtwolame.la` and return `libtwolame/.libs/libtwolame.dylib` (or `libtwolame/.libs/libtwolame.so` on Linux)?
Or anything that can be done with automake macros?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get libtool library output filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766820/get-libtool-library-output-filename)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a version controlled file containing the list of exported symbols (say, `libtwolame.sym`) you can just tell libtool to only export the symbols listed in that file.

It only takes three lines added to `Makefile.am`:

```
EXTRA_DIST += libtwolame.sym
libtwolame_la_DEPENDENCIES += ${srcdir}/libtwolame.sym
libtwolame_la_LDFLAGS += -export-symbols ${srcdir}/libtwolame.sym
```

We have been using that system for [libgphoto2](https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2) for a long time to control the list of symbols exported to the users of our library as well for the symbols exported by the dynamically loaded camera drivers.

Caveat: Quoting the [libtool manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html) (emphasis mine):

> -export-symbols symfile
>
> Tells the linker to export only the symbols listed in symfile. The symbol file should end in .sym and must contain the name of one symbol per line. **This option has no effect on some platforms.** By default all symbols are exported.

Comment: Thanks, that is really useful to know. Upvoting but not selecting as correct answer because as other question that LegendofPedro links to, I don't think it is actually possible to do what I originally asked.